# How can the thesis structure be defined for PDF generation?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, pdf, chapters, parts

My thesis consists of these hierarchical elements:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\include{020-tex}
\end{document
```

where `020-tex.tex` contains

```
\input{030-preface}
\part{First Part}
\input{040-Theory-Part-I}

\part{Second Part}
\input{040-Theory-Part-II}

\bibliographystyle{achemso.bst}
\bibliography{citations-part-i,citations-part-ii}

\input{080-sup-mat}
```

E.g. `040-Theory-Part-I` is formatted as

```
\chapter*{Theoretical Framework}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Theoretical Framework}
```

such that the `TOC` lists the chapter, but no numbering is used.

In the TOC, the hierarchy levels are correctly formatted, i.e. sections are sections, chapters appear as chapters and so on. But when I view the PDF in Previews, in the sidebar which allows to "browse" the content and expand chapters, the bibliography is hierarchically under Part II, while it should be on the same level as Parts I and II. So the bibliography only appears when I expand Part II.
Also the appendix appears only under Part II, while it should be on the same level as the parts and the introductions. Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get the red enclosed content to be on the same level as the vertical line?

Comment: What is your question? That's unclear. In any case, I think you should read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You have the `\include` and `\input` commands reversed. If you really want to profit of `\include`, use it for chapter files, not for the big "catch it all" file.

Comment: While I understand your desire, strictly speaking, that is the correct layout from a traditional point of view (and from the same perspective, things like your preface are at the 'wrong' level).  But you should load package `bookmark` and make use of the `\bookmark` command.  Package `bookmark` should be on your list of always-loaded packages.

Comment: At what level should the `preface` be then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483396/how-to-explicitly-end-a-part-in-latex-with-hyperref). (Summary: use the bookmark package and 
`\bookmarksetup{startatroot}`.) I just had exactly the same problem, it worked fine. (Using the Memoir class.)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I elaborated on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, since it seems this is a problem with your hyperlinks in pdf.

First, make sure to load `\usepackage[pdftex,pdfpagelabels,bookmarks,hyperindex,hyperfigures]{hyperref}`.

Second, try using this:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{achemso.bst}
\bibliography{citations-part-i,citations-part-iia}
```

For the appendix, try:

```
\appendix
\input{Papers}
```

In the Papers.tex file use "Paper1", "Paper2", etc. as chapters.

Comment: I tried, I cant fix it...

Comment: Please make sure *hyperrf* is the last package loaded in the preamble

Comment: Don't use `pdftex` option with `hyperref`. It can detect the workflow.

Comment: @MarioS.E.: It fails to compile if `hyperref` is loaded after `bookmark`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, all suggested options fail.
The solution is to use the `\bookmark` package and to include these commands to indicate the end of part ii.

```
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\addtocontents{toc}{\bigskip}
```

As provided by @Andrew.