# Why I shouldn't load pdftex option with hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex

According to @percusse in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106028/27833), I shouldn't load the `pdftex` option with the `hyperref` package. Why is it?

Comment: A direct link to the comment in question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106023/how-can-the-thesis-structure-be-defined-for-pdf-generation/106028#comment231169_106028

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would say you won't need to tell `hyperref` as it detects this on it's own. If you load `hyperref` by

```
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
```

and use another engine like XeTeX or LaTeX+dvips it could cause errors as `hyperref` adds `\special` commands to do its stuff.

These `\special` commands are different with each engine (pdfTeX produces PDF immediately—so no `\special` is neccessary—while dvips for example won't and therefore needs those `\special` commands in the DVI-file, created by LaTeX (or TeX). These `\special` commands will be processed by dvips to realise the features of `hyperref`).

All possible engine drivers and more information is provided by the [`hyperref` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf).

I think you should only use those option only if you get trouble by processing your documents. But be aware of it, if you might change the engine.