# Email inside \author{} not producing clickable email with \maketitle

Tags: titles, email, author

Using `\href{mailto:x@y.z}{x@y.z}` I am able to render my email as a clickable text. Is there a way to add email as a part of `\author{}` field, and have `\maketitle` generate a link that will call an email client when clicked? I am using KOMA-Script.
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,titlepage=true]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  pdfauthor={x},
  pdftitle={x},
  colorlinks=false,
  urlbordercolor={0.9 0.5 0.1},
  pdfborderstyle={/S/D/W 1}
}

\begin{document}
\titlehead{\centering x\\y\\z}
\subject{my subject}
\title{my title}
\author{author1\\x@y.z}
\date{2017}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Also, any comments on the preamble regarding (improper) use of packages are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, get rid of the `pdftex` option.

Comment: Can't you just add that `\href` stuff into `\author`?

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried to use your proposed `\href` command instead of the textual email address in the `\author` command? When I view the resulting pdf, my viewer tries to open an email client when I click on the email address.

Comment: `\author{author1\\ \href{mailto:x@y.z}{x@y.z}}` is ugly style but seems to work fine. Can you elaborate what difficulties your are facing?

Comment: why is `pdftex` option unnecessary?

Comment: See [Why I shouldn't load pdftex option with hyperref?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106161/110998)

Answer (score 3):

As  [gernot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/110998/gernot) and [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) suggested `\author{author1\\ \href{mailto:x@y.z}{x@y.z}}` solves the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and more powerful answer is to `\usepackage{url}` and then just code `\author{Name, \url{foo_bar@gmail.com}}`.

Re packages: do NOT use geometry to typeset wide lines of body text.  It is well established that people have trouble comprehending wide lines of text.   The practical maximum is about 14cm, as coded in the standard LaTeX.   If you want your work understood, then do NOT typeset with body text wider than 14cm.

Conversely, if you are writing a report with embarrassing information in it than you want to obfuscate, then use body text as wide as you can.